# How to do count from dataframe python?

Tags: python

I have data like as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020.2.1','2020.2.1','2020.2.1','2020.2.2','2020.2.1'],
                'fips':[4,5,4,5,5]})
```

and I want to get a result counting the frequency of fips each day like as below, but I don't want to ignore the overlapped index column (desired output):

```
pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020.2.1','2020.2.1','2020.2.2'],
                'fips':[4,5,5], 'count':[2,2,1]})
```

I tried `df.groupby(['date','fips']).size()`
But it ignore the index value at second row and first column '2020.2.1'.
Thanks in advance for your help..

Comment: Have you tried df[['date', 'fips']].value_counts() ?

Comment: Yeah, I did. but it gives error saying 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Comment: Which version of pandas do you have? I tried it worked for me

Comment: In the meantime, this should work too: `df.groupby(['date', 'fips']).fips.agg(fips='first', freq=len)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. but what I am trying to do is not to ignore the second row index column which is '2020.2.1' for second row. I want it visible twice in the dataframe. but only show only once..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, it is present twice already (if you look at the index of the dataframe, you should see 2 entries of `fips` for `date=2020.2.1`. (or maybe I'm missing something). Maybe doing this would make more sense to you? `df.groupby(['date', 'fips']).fips.agg(freq=len).reset_index()`

Comment: df.groupby(['date', 'fips']).fips.agg(freq=len).reset_index()... This works.. Good call Nakor,, I am sorry if I made you confused.

Comment: No worry :) Let me know if it does not make sense and I can make a post with more details

Answer (score 1):

Just reset the index to make the first column 'fully visible'

```
df2 = df.groupby(['date','fips'])['fips'].agg(['count']).reset_index()
```